# Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: polynomials, recursion, difference-equations, iteration

How could I write the Chebyshev polynomial as a function that uses `Nest`? Also, how could I write it using recursion?

Furthermore, how can I show that $T_n(x)=\frac12((x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n$?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: `ChebyshevT[n, x]`

Comment: [`ChebyshevT`](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/ChebyshevT/)

Answer (score 6):

The way to use `Nest[]` for computing the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind is to recognize that a three-term recurrence is equivalent to repeated multiplication by a certain $2\times 2$ matrix. To wit,

```
With[{n = 5}, First[Nest[{{2 x, -1}, {1, 0}}.# &, {x, 1}, n - 1]]] // Expand
   5 x - 20 x^3 + 16 x^5

ChebyshevT[5, x]
   5 x - 20 x^3 + 16 x^5
```

Similarly for the second kind polynomial,

```
With[{n = 5}, First[Nest[{{2 x, -1}, {1, 0}}.# &, {2 x, 1}, n - 1]]] // Expand
   6 x - 32 x^3 + 32 x^5

ChebyshevU[5, x]
   6 x - 32 x^3 + 32 x^5
```

Of course, this formulation can be simplified by just using the action form of `MatrixPower[]`:

```
With[{n = 5}, First[MatrixPower[{{2 x, -1}, {1, 0}}, n - 1, {x, 1}]]] // Expand
   5 x - 20 x^3 + 16 x^5
```

(This formulation works out because the difference equation satisfied by both Chebyshev polynomials has *constant coefficients*, similar to the Fibonacci and Lucas cases. For other orthogonal polynomials like Legendre, things are less simple.)

---

As for the non-trigonometric representation of the Chebyshev polynomials, you can coax *Mathematica* into producing them like so:

```
FunctionExpand[DifferenceRootReduce[ChebyshevT[n, x], n]]
   1/2 ((x - Sqrt[-1 + x^2])^n + (x + Sqrt[-1 + x^2])^n)

Assuming[n ∈ Integers, 
         FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[DifferenceRootReduce[ChebyshevU[n, x], n]]]]
   1/2 ((x - Sqrt[-1 + x^2])^n + (x + Sqrt[-1 + x^2])^n +
        (x (-(x - Sqrt[-1 + x^2])^n + (x + Sqrt[-1 + x^2])^n))/Sqrt[-1 + x^2])
```

Comment: How could I also use RSolve to get the $T_n(x)=\frac12((x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n$ equation?

Comment: What did you try with `RSolve[]`?

Comment: I've tried RSolve[T[x] == 1/2*((x - Sqrt[x^2 - 1])^n + (x + Sqrt[x^2 - 1])^n), T[x], x]
which i think works

Answer (score 1):

Recursive:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[0, _] = 1;
f[1, x_] = x;
f[n_, x_] := 2 x f[n - 1, x] - f[n - 2, x]
```

With Nest:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[0, _] = 1;
f[n_, x_] := Nest[{#[[2]], 2 x #[[2]] - #[[1]]} &, {1, x}, n - 1][[2]]
```

To show `ChebyshevT[n, x] == 1/2 ((x - Sqrt[x^2 - 1])^n + (x + Sqrt[x^2 - 1])^n)`  you show first, that the recursion relation is fulfilled. And then you show that the the recursion start is o.k.

```
ClearAll[f, n];
ff[n_, x_] = 1/2 ((x - Sqrt[x^2 - 1])^n + (x + Sqrt[x^2 - 1])^n);
ff[n, x] == 2 x ff[n - 1, x] - ff[n - 2, x] // Simplify
ff[0, x] == 1
ff[1, x] == x
(*True,True,True*)
```

Instead, you may show that `ff[n,x]` fulfills the Chebyshev Differential equation:

```
ClearAll[f, n, x];
ff[n_, x_] = 1/2 ((x - Sqrt[x^2 - 1])^n + (x + Sqrt[x^2 - 1])^n);
(1 - x^2) D[ff[n, x], {x, 2}] - x  D[ff[n, x], x] +  n^2 ff[n, x] // Simplify
(*0*)
```